# Fisheye and Pinhole pixel correlation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, fisheye

I have a camera system which has both fish eye camera and pinhole camera. These cameras capture the same image. My task is to map a pixel on fish eye image to a pixel on pinhole image (at an acceptable error). I have covered some papers such as OPEN CV fisheye functions in this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html)

1. Is this mapping method some how similar to a pinhole projection or "flattening" a fisheye image ?
2. Does anyone know some references or papers about this method both mathematically and programmatically ?
   Thank you so much for your help

Comment: do you really have a pinhole camera without any distortions? All in all, the mapping typically can't be constant but depends on the distance to the captured objects  (unless both cameras have the same ootical center). See stereo calibration.